# Chikka SMS API always Convert

Tags: php, api, sms

Good Day to all of you.
I have a problem in Chikka SMS API
I downloaded the script from github and I tried to run it and it was successful. I received the message but the problem is spaces and other characters are encoded.

This is the code that I used

```
<?php
include('ChikkaSMS.php');

$clientId = 'xxxxx';
$secretKey = 'xxxxxx';
$shortCode = 'xxxxxx';
$chikkaAPI = new ChikkaSMS($clientId,$secretKey,$shortCode);
$response = $chikkaAPI->sendText('UNIQUEMESSAGEID', 'MOBILENUMBER', 'YOURMESSAGE');?>
```

> From: https://github.com/mojics/chikka_sms_api

Comment: Presumably you must have written your own code from this? How are you getting the data into your script? Please provide the full code that you have written so that we may help you

Comment: thats the exact code. I tried the API Code that they provide but it doesn't work. I tried mine too but it doesnt work. It seems they always encode my messages.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys if I disturbed you. I already fixed by my self :) .
I removed the urlencode(); from the ChikkaSMS.php file :)