# Need working sms for chikka api in PHP

Tags: php, api, sms

Good day everyone! specially to those who are experts in chikka sms api

I have a problem that took me 3 hrs but still no luck...

I decided to choose [chikka](https://api.chikka.com) as my sms api on our capstone project...

this is the code I downloaded in GitHUB and a user here in stackoverflow ([Maverick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340867/chikka-sms-api-always-convert)) post also a thread about his config is working but mine is not...

this is the code:

Example.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This file will show a simple implementation on how to send SMS using Chikka API
 * @author Ronald Allan Mojica
 * 
 */
include('ChikkaSMS.php');

$clientId = 'b43964ce5433fecdc4ee6fd7717xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$secretKey = '49502a1819b22c8465d5d6783d2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$shortCode = '29290xxxxxx';
$chikkaAPI = new ChikkaSMS($clientId,$secretKey,$shortCode);
$response = $chikkaAPI->sendText('1234561', '63906xxxxxxx', 'tests');

header("HTTP/1.1 " . $response->status . " " . $response->message);

exit($response->$description);
```

ChikkaSMS.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Class ChikkaSMS Class handles the methods and properties of sending or receiving an SMS message.
 * The main inspiration of this class was from Nexmo PHP Library
 *  
 * Usage: $var = new NexoMessage ( $account_key, $account_password );
 * Methods:
 *      
 *      sendText($requestId, $to, $message)
 *      receiveTxt()
 *      reply()
 *      receiveNotifications()
 *      
 */

class ChikkaSMS {

//authorization
private $clientId = '';
private $secretKey = '';
private $shortCode = '';
private $sslVerify = false;

//Chikka's default URI for sending SMS
private $chikkaSendUrl = 'https://post.chikka.com/smsapi/request';

private $sendRequest = 'send';
private $receiveRequest = 'incoming';
private $replyRequest = 'reply';
private $notificationRequest = 'outgoing';

//Based from Chikka's price breakdown
private $requestCost = array(
    'free' => 'FREE', 
    '1' =>1, 
    '2.5'=> 2.5, 
    '5'=> 5, 
    '10' => 10, 
    '15' => 15
    );

private $expectedChikkaResponse = array(
    'message_type'=>'',
    'short_code' => '',
    'message_id' => '',
    'status' => '',
    'credits_cost' => '',
    'timestamp' => '');

private $responseAccepted = array(
    'status' => 'Accepted',
    'message' => 'Message has been successfully processed.',
    'code' => 202
    );

private $responseDenied = array(
    'status' => 'Error',
    'message' => 'Message has not been processed.',
    'code' => 400
    );

/**
 * [__construct description]
 * @param [type] $clientId  [description]
 * @param [type] $secretKey [description]
 * @param [type] $shortCode [description]
 */
public function __construct($clientId, $secretKey, $shortCode){
    $this->clientId = $clientId;
    $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
    $this->shortCode = $shortCode;
}


/**
 * SendText allows sending of SMS message to Chikka API
 * @param type $requestId This identifier should be unique or your message will not be sent and you will be deducted
 * @param type $to  The mobile number you are sending an SMS
 * @param type $message The SMS message 
 */

public function sendText($messageID, $to, $message) {
    $messageID = strip_tags($messageID);

    //Request ID should not be blank
    if(strlen($messageID) < 1){
        trigger_error('Message ID is required');
        return false;
    }
    
    // Making sure strings are UTF-8 encoded
    if (!is_numeric($to) && !mb_check_encoding($to, 'UTF-8')) {
        trigger_error('TO needs to be a valid UTF-8 encoded string');
        return false;
    }

    if (!mb_check_encoding($message, 'UTF-8')) {
        trigger_error('Message needs to be a valid UTF-8 encoded string');
        return false;
    }
    
    //urlencode 
    $message = urlencode($message);

    //sendText post params
    $sendData = array(
        'message_type' => $this->sendRequest,
        'mobile_number' => $to,
        'shortcode' => $this->shortCode,
        'message_id' => $messageID,
        'message' => $message
        );
    
    //send Api request to Chikka and process it 
    return $this->sendApiRequest($sendData);
}

public function receiveText() {
    
}


/**
 * Reply - ability to send reply message  
 *
 * @param [String] [requestID] [The requestID supplied by Chikka SMS]
 * @param [String] [messageID] [Unique identifier]
 * @param [String] [to] [mobile number starint 63]
 * @param [String] [cost] [Amount to charge: Free, 1, 2.50, 5, 10, 15]
 * @param [String] [message] [UTF-8 string]
 */
public function reply($requestID, $messageID, $to, $cost, $message) {
    //Request ID should not be blank
    if(strlen($messageID) < 1){
        trigger_error('Message ID is required');
        return false;
    }
    
    // Making sure strings are UTF-8 encoded
    if (!is_numeric($to) && !mb_check_encoding($to, 'UTF-8')) {
        trigger_error('TO needs to be a valid UTF-8 encoded string');
        return false;
    }

    if (!mb_check_encoding($message, 'UTF-8')) {
        trigger_error('Message needs to be a valid UTF-8 encoded string');
        return false;
    }

    if (array_key_exists($cost, $this->requestCost)){
        trigger_error('The cost value only allows FREE, 1, 2.5, 5, 10, and 15');
        return false;
    }

    $message = urlencode($message);

    //reply post params
    $replyData = array(
        'message_type' => $this->ReplyRequest,
        'mobile_number' => $to,
        'shortcode' => $this->shortCode,
        'message_id' => $messageID,
        'message' => $message,
        'cost' => $this->requestCost[$cost],
        'request_id' => $requestID
        );
    
    return $this->sendApiRequest($replyData);
}

/**
 * [fetchNotifications description] removed the logic of showing Accepted and Error on receiving notification from Chikka API
 * the operator should be the one doing it
 *  
 */
public function receiveNotifications() {
    $fromChikka = $_POST;
    
    if (count(array_diff_key($this->expectedChikkaResponse, $fromChikka)) != 0) {
        $fromChikka = null;
    }
    return $fromChikka;
}

/**
 * sendApiRequest - the functionality that sends request to Chikka API endpoint
 * @param  [array] $data post params 
 * @return [object]       
 */
private function sendApiRequest($data){
    $data = array_merge($data, array('client_id'=>$this->clientId, 'secret_key' => $this->secretKey));
    //  build a request query from arrays of data 
    $post = http_build_query($data);

    // If available, use CURL
    if (function_exists('curl_version')) {

        $to_chikka = curl_init( $this->chikkaSendUrl );
        curl_setopt( $to_chikka, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $to_chikka, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $to_chikka, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );

        if (!$this->sslVerify) {
            curl_setopt( $to_chikka, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        }

        $from_chikka = curl_exec( $to_chikka );
        curl_close ( $to_chikka );

    } elseif (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
        // No CURL available so try the awesome file_get_contents
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $post
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $from_chikka = file_get_contents($this->chikkaSendUrl, false, $context);

    } else {
        // No way of sending a HTTP post :(
        return false;
    }

    return $this->parseApiResponse($from_chikka, $data['message_type']);
}

/**
 * parseApiResponse - process and handle Chikka api responses
 * @param  [array] $response    Response from Chikka API
 * @param  [string] $requestType This is the message type of the sms 
 * @return [type]              
 */
private function parseApiResponse($response, $requestType = null){
    $response = json_decode($response,true);
    if($requestType){
        $response['request_type'] = $requestType;
    }
    
    return json_decode(json_encode($response));;
}

}

?>
```

and these are the error that I encounter

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$status in C:\xampp\htdocs\ict\sms\example.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$message in C:\xampp\htdocs\ict\sms\example.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\ict\sms\example.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\ict\sms\example.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

"The main inspiration of this class was from [Nexmo PHP Library](https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib)"

Instead, I recommend using [Nexmo's](https://www.nexmo.com) [SMS API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api) as all it takes is an HTTP call to send an SMS.

How to send an SMS (in PHP):

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query([
    'api_key' => API_KEY, 
    'api_secret' => API_SECRET,
    'to' => YOUR_NUMBER, 
    'from' => NEXMO_NUMBER, 
    'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo' 
]);

$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! How many free text messages they offer for the outbound message on FREE account? It's just for presentation on our capstone project... is there an SMS api that will reset at midnight? something like that...

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <?php
        $arr_post_body = array(
            "message_type" => "SEND",
            "mobile_number" => "639181234567",
            "shortcode" => "29290123456",
            "message_id" => "12345678901234567890123456789012",
            "message" => urlencode("Welcome to My Service!"),
            "client_id" => "1e6d92a6e8794a7bb6aea67f008420e56a0272dfb21047369dc1ea0c9c8f8a19",
            "secret_key" => "502f3b2ecce940f5b750dab07bf6b222de86f6e270a6427e9a0ea6b194bb4bdc"
        );

        $query_string = "";
        foreach($arr_post_body as $key => $frow)
        {
            $query_string .= '&'.$key.'='.$frow;
        }

        $URL = "https://post.chikka.com/smsapi/request";

        $curl_handler = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POST, count($arr_post_body));
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $response = curl_exec($curl_handler);
        curl_close($curl_handler);

        exit(0);



    ?>
```

[image]

Reference : https://api.chikka.com/docs/getting-started#message-sender

Comment: My problem is solve is just that chikka won't allow me to send multiple numbers if my account status is trial.